# How to run a multiple line command

Tags: command-line

I am trying to follow some instructions, that seem to be a multiple line command line argument.  Here it is:

You will need a couple of packages before getting to work. Install them using the following command: 
Debian based Systems:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential cmake gettext kdeartwork libqwt-dev \
kdelibs5-dev libxtst-dev libqt4-sql-sqlite libphonon-dev libattica0.4 libattica-dev zlib1g-dev \
libasound2-dev julius libpocketsphinx-dev libpocketsphinx3 sphinxtrain libsphinxbase-dev \
libsphinxbase3
```

When I simply copy and paste that into the command line, and run it, the computer says:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package kdeartwork

Comment: what version of Ubuntu are you using? if it's 18.04 "kdeartwork" is not included in the repositories.

Comment: It looks like actually running a multiline command is not the problem, as the title seems to indicate.